# RxJS: an interval that starts right away

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm making a simple toy angular2 project that hits an url every 5 seconds.  Right now I have it so that it polls the url, and when the the document loads it doesn't wait. But it seems really clunky.  Is there a better more elegant solution to this?

```
Observable.interval(1000 * 5)
      .flatMap(() => this.http.get(url))
      .merge(this.http.get(url)) // Merges a stream that starts right away!!!
      .map((res:Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: Have you tried `startWith`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `timer` instead

```
Observable.timer(0, 1000 * 5)
          .flatMap(() => this.http.get(url),
                   (_, res) => res.json);
```

`timer` takes an initial delay before emitting its first event, and then emits just like `interval` every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 13):

I think you could try something like this:

```
    import { interval } from "rxjs";
    import { map, mergeMap, startWith } from "rxjs/operators";

    interval(1000 * 5).pipe(
      startWith(0),
      mergeMap(() => this.http.get(url)),
      map((res:Response) => res.json())
    );
```

This will emit a value immediatly and then once every 5 seconds.

Check out the documentation [here.](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js%7EObservable.html#instance-method-startWith)

Comment: Thanks Luka Jacobowitz! You saved me some hours of digging.

Comment: No Problem at all!